What specific LinkedIn notification to disable to stop "Don’t miss conversations in..." emails?
LinkedIn is spamming me with emails like this:

If you click the unsubscribe link in the email, it takes you to LinkedIn's overall Notifications settings page rather than the specific notification which should be disabled
(LinkedIn are capable of doing this from links within their UI, so I can only speculate as to why they don't when coming from the email spam...)

Each one of those options has approximately the same number of sub-options behind - it's like those "so you think you want to disable cookies eh?" website dialogs x100
I've tried disabling email notifications on maybe the 10 most obvious choices but I'm still getting these emails. I can't disable email notifications from LinkedIn wholesale because I need them to get a job.
I feel it would be a service to the internet to have this information quickly and specifically documented somewhere. Maybe webapps.SE can help where LinkedIn has failed?

I also receive those emails. In the unsubscribe link there's the string "eml-email_groups_recommended_by_admin", but disabling "Groups -> Groups Recommendations" didn't do it for me.

yeah those unsubscribe links seem to go to URLs which no longer exist, so get redirected to the top-level Notification Settings page on LinkedIn. Pretty shocking that they can't update this given how much subscriptions cost...

Did you find how to turn this off?
